# Is there a firebase security rule to only allow appending to a list?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'd like to create a simple chat app, but I don't want *any* user to be able to edit the chat-entry list - but I *do* want any user to be able to append to it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can utilize [exists](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/rulesdatasnapshot/exists.html) in your write rule:

```
"chat_list": {
   "$chat_entry": {
       ".write": " !data.exists() "
   }
}
```

This will make it possible to append but not to write to a record which already exists.

Comment: See edits above by Kato. The key is to assign the write rule to the *children* of the list.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I found a solution (having my own service do the append, and giving the clients read-only access otherwise) and totally forgot about this question...

Comment: Yeah, I just don't see that @nathancahill. `!data.exists()` means you can only write if the data does not exist. Enough said. You probably made a mistake implementing if you saw differently.

Comment: Sorry @Kato, you're correct. I'm not sure why I was seeing that behavior with my rules. Just tested in a clean project and your answer works as described. Deleting my answer and upvoting yours.

Comment: Cheers, @nathancahill. Thanks for contributing to the convo and for adding your thoughts. I love how interactive the Firebase community is.

Comment: What would be the equivalent on firestore?

Comment: @sap sounds like a great question that deserves it's own Stack Overflow Q&A. The equivalent is `allow write: if exists(path/to/data)`. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/)

Answer (score 0):

over a decade late to the party, but maybe this

```
// Only allow to APPEND to myArray
allow update: 
  if request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['myArray'])
  && request.resource.data.myArray is list
  && request.resource.data.myArray.size() == resource.data.myArray.size() + 1
  && request.resource.data.myArray.diff(resource.data.myArray).affectedKeys().hasOnly([resource.data.myArray.size()]);
```